# Numbering theorem-like environments

Tags: numbering, theorems

I would like all my theorem-like environments (theorem, example, etc.) to be numbered but such that the number appears *before* the environment's name, more or less like this:

**1. Theorem**

**2. Example**

How can I do this?

Comment: How do you define your `theorem` and `example` environments at the moment - using a package or not? If you're using any package, please provide this information as well, since there are many packages available for defining `theorem` (or other) environments, each of which might require a specific solution.

Comment: @Werner: I don't really know much about packages (or latex, really), usually I just add a bunch of them until everything works. But I guess **amsthm** would be the one responsible for generating my Theorem environment. All my other environments are defined by \newtheorem{counter}{name}. Did I answer your question at all?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) provides `\swapnumbers` which reverses the display of `Theorem <num>.` to `<num> Theorem.` Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\swapnumbers % Switch number/label style
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{example}
This is an example.
\end{example}
\end{document}​
```

In the above example, the `example` environment shares the `theorem` counter. Moreover, both are defined with the `plain` style. There are others available, as shown in the [`amsthm` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf).

Answer (score 10):

`amsthm` has a command `\swapnumbers` that, when specified before the `\theoremstyle` or `\newtheorem` elenments for which numbers are to come first, will do what you want.

for details, see the [`amsthm` user's guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf), section 4.2 on "number swapping".

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways to create `theorem` like environments. Here's an option using `ntheorem`

[image: screenshot]

The trick is to make a new `theoremstyle` using the arguments

- `##1` which is the name of the theorem
- `##2` which is the number of the theorem
- `##3` which is the optional title of the theorem

Using the examples in the `ntheorem` documentation as a guide, you can tweak this to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{numberfirst}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont{##2\theorem@separator\hskip\labelsep ##1}]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont{##2\theorem@separator\hskip\labelsep ##1} (##3)]}%
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{numberfirst}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}[Optional title]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mytheorem}

\end{document}
```