# Change from "Theorem 10.1" to "10.1 Theorem"

Tags: numbering, theorems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numbering theorem-like environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44124/)

How can I change the order in which theorems are displayed? I want 10.1 Theorem and not Theorem 10.1 Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) It's usually best to compose a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) In your case, it would have been helpful to know which `theorem` package you're using- `amsthm`, `ntheorem`, other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, but all involve loading an additional package, as the default format of theorems in LaTeX is quite rigid.

The easiest way is to add to your preamble

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\swapnumbers
```

Alternatively, the `ntheorem` package provides the `change` theoremstyle, so declaring

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{change}
```

will do.

You may want to look at the `thmtools` package for other customizations of your theorem-like environments.