# Theorem and lemma and proposition numberings with the numbers first

Tags: math-mode, formatting, numbering, theorems

If one considers the following MWE one sees that theorems and lemmas have their number as a suffix:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatletter\let\TTTemp\cap\makeatother
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}
\makeatletter\let\cap\TTTemp\makeatother
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocbibind}


\allowdisplaybreaks


\newbox\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnCornerHgt
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$\ulcorner$}
\global\gnCornerHgt=\ht\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnArgHgt
\def\Godelnum #1{%
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$#1$}%
\gnArgHgt=\ht\gnBoxA%
\ifnum     \gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt \gnArgHgt=0pt%
\else \advance \gnArgHgt by -\gnCornerHgt%
\fi \raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\ulcorner$} \box\gnBoxA %
\raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\urcorner$}}

\newcommand{\bleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bleqinn\relax}}
\newcommand{\bleqinn}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \raisebox{0.04ex}{\scalebox{1.24}[1.15]{$#1\blacktriangleleft$}}\cr
    $#1\leq$\cr
  }%
}

\newcommand{\blt}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bltinn\relax}} \newcommand{\bltinn}[2]{ \ooalign{ \raisebox{0.04ex}{\scalebox{1.23}[1.22]{$#1\blacktriangleleft$}}\cr $#1$\cr } }


\newcommand\fat[1]{\ThisStyle{\hstretch{1.4}{\ooalign{%
  \kern.46pt$\SavedStyle#1$\cr\kern.33pt$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern.2pt$\SavedStyle#1$\cr$\SavedStyle#1$}}}}
\def\fvee{\mathbin{\fat{\vee}}}

\newcommand*{\aoverb}[2]{\ensuremath{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand\updown[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\ensuremath{#1}}}
\newcommand\atangle[2]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{\ensuremath{#2}}}

\renewcommand*{\koppa}{\ensuremath{\text{\textgreek\coppa}}}
\renewcommand*{\Koppa}{\ensuremath{\text{\textgreek\Coppa}}}

%\newcommand*{\koppa}{\ensuremath{\c{k}}}
%\newcommand*{\Koppa}{\ensuremath{\c{K}}}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{cannon}[theorem]{Cannon}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{hint}[theorem]{Hint}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{postulate}[theorem]{Postulate}
\newtheorem{postulation}[theorem]{Postulation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}

\title{Test}

\author{Frode Bj\o rdal}

\date{}

\begin{document}


    \section{Test}

    \begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{lemma}
    This is a lemma.
    \end{lemma}

    \begin{proposition}
    Ths is a proposition
    \end{proposition}


    \end{document}
```

How can I have the numbers as a prefix? Just adding the amsthm with swapnumbers give errors.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95356/change-from-theorem-10-1-to-10-1-theorem

Comment: I do not use the amsthm package, but rather:

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}
\makeatletter\let\cap\TTTemp\makeatother
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{scalerel}

So the linked question does not help me.

Comment: Are there philosophical reasons not to load also `amsthm`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I get errors. I will edit the question with the full preamble for  you to see.

Comment: Just remove your definition of `proof` and use the much better one by `amsthm` or, if you prefer a bad one, do `\renewenvironment{proof}{...}{...}`

Comment: I now resolved the problem myself and vote to close the question.