# Numbering theorems in the left margin

Tags: theorems, amsthm

My question is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44124/numbering-theorem-like-environments) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59244/theorem-name-numbering-in-margin). I would like to have the theorem number in the left margin (0.6em spacing to the main text) and the Name 'Theorem' should be justified to the main text. The solution should made with the `amsthm`package, because I've made my very specific `proof` environment with `\renewenvironment` from `amsthm`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,lmodern,libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
{\topsep}               %space above
{\topsep}               %space below
{}                      %bodyfont
{}                      %indent
{\bfseries}             %headfont
{}                      %punctuation
{0.6em}                 %space after head
{#2 #1 #3}              %theoremheadspec
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] 

\begin{theorem}
Let $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continious and let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a).
\end{align*}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This looks like

[image]

But it should look like this (this was made with the `ntheorem` package):

[image: this was made with ntheorem]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you read this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59244/10898

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `\llap` command for `left overlap`

```
{\llap{#2 }#1 #3}              %theoremheadspec
```

Here's a complete MWE to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
{\topsep}               %space above
{\topsep}               %space below
{}                      %bodyfont
{}                      %indent
{\bfseries}             %headfont
{}                      %punctuation
{0.6em}                 %space after head
{\llap{#2 }#1 #3}              %theoremheadspec
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] 

\begin{theorem}
Let $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continious and let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a).
\end{align*}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No fair! You won me by a few seconds :-)

Comment: @azetina if it makes you feel better, that's happened to me *a lot* on the site :)

Comment: I could imagine. ;-)

Comment: Since the OP wants `0.6em` I'd say `\llap{#2\hspace{.6em}}`